# Having worked overseas and accrued a pension, can I transfer it to my country of origin?

Tags: united-kingdom, pension, south-africa

As a Brit who worked in South Africa for a few years and accrued a pension, now I've returned is it possible to transfer said pension tax-free to a UK pension provider (SIPP or otherwise)?

Comment: Is this a private pension scheme that will allow you to convert it to a cash value?

Comment: @DJClayworth yes it is